# How to make dialog boxes in tab controls

Tags: c++, winapi

I use C++ in Visual Studio Express 2013 on Windows 7.

I am trying to make a program and have started a form with a toolbar, tab controls with 7 tabs, and a statusbar. So far all works OK.

[image: My form so far]

I am stuck here with code to find out which tab is pressed and how to add a dialog in the display area for this tab.

I do understand I have to create DialogBoxEx for the display area. But how?

In my `WM_NOTIFY` handler, I have to find out which tab is pressed. But how?

In `OnSelChanged()`, I have to close the previous dialog and open the next tab's dialog box. But how?

I also need subroutines for every dialogbox to handle what I want in each dialogbox. But how?

A little code snippet:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
    switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
    {
        case TCN_SELCHANGE:
        {
            OnSelChanged(hWnd);
        }
        break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
break;
```

```
VOID OnSelChanged(hwnd)
{
    // send a message to statusbar just for check
    SendMessage(hWndStatusBar, SB_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"OnSelChange");
    return;
}
```

I have read [How to Create a Tabbed Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298366.aspx) as well, but it is a little crowded for me at the moment.

Comment: Did you see the big note at the top? If you use property sheets and property pages some of the low-level stuff is taken care of for you.

Comment: You do not create a separate dialog box for each tab page. You create a *child dialog* for each tab page, Z-order them above the tab control (they should be siblings of the tab control, not children of the tab control), and hide and show them in response to the notifications. Tab control messages can tell you which tab to show. Check MSDN.

Comment: Expanding on @andlabs' comment, the Tab Control often confuses developers, because it implements such a perfect illusion. While it **looks** like the tab control hosts the individual pages, it really is a sibling to them, that switches the visibility appropriately.